# Create a PDF from data in a database

Tags: android, pdf-generation

How to convert sql database of android  into pdf file. 
Actually I have to convert a resume made through android into pdf file so that it can be uploaded to a website.

Comment: So, do you want to know how to use the database, or do you want to know how to convert to PDF in Android? Which one is it?

Comment: i want to know how to convert the data from database into pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from the sql db and use the [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) Library to write data into a pdf.